# Video Ad (show video then ad)

Tags: php, jquery

Doe's anyone know how I can replicate this? I'd like to show an a promo code after the video plays on my website.

Like the current chipotle facebook ad.

[Facebook Ad](http://apps.facebook.com/videocoupon/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have the Flash movie call your JavaScript function when it finishes playing. Alternatively you might use HTML5 video tag but it would work only on modern browsers.

For example if you are using [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) then you would have to register a callback when the movie finishes playing using something like this:

```
flowplayer().onFinish(yourFunction);
```

and define yourFunction to do what you want to do when the movie finishes playing, like showing more content etc.

```
function yourFunction() {
    $('#promo').show();
}
```

If you have your promo in a hidden div with id promo like this:

```
<div id="promo" style="display: none">Your hidden div</div>
```

This is just the most basic example, you probably would like to make the code less obvious than to include it in HTML.